# Paket access denied on Fake

Tags: c#, batch-file, f#-fake, paket

I have a problem with Paket when it tries to pack the dlls for my project, I just get a "Paket failed with: Access to the path is denied", I have the following configuration

In the postbuild event for VisualStudio I call a bat file to call the script for fake

build.bat

```
@ECHO off

cls

SET TargetName=%1
SET BuildMode=%2
SET SolutionDir=%~dp0

rem Get latests version of Paket
"%~dp0.paket\paket.bootstrapper.exe"
IF errorlevel 1 (
    ECHO error on paket.bootstrapper
)

rem Download the dependencies specified by the paket.lock file into the packages/ directory. 
"%~dp0.paket\paket.exe" restore
IF errorlevel 1 (
    ECHO error on paket.restore
)

rem ECHO Starting FAKE build.fsx
"%SolutionDir%packages\FAKE\tools\FAKE.exe" "%SolutionDir%buildPackage.fsx" -ev TargetName %TargetName% -ev BuildMode %BuildMode% -ev SolutionDir "%SolutionDir%
```

build.fsx

```
open Fake.AssemblyInfoFile
open System
open Paket

//CommandLineArguments
let TargetName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TargetName")    
let SolutionDir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SolutionDir")
let BuildMode = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BuildMode")

//Paths
let AssemblyFilePath = SolutionDir + TargetName + @"\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"
let PaketPath = SolutionDir + @".paket\paket.exe"
let PaketOutPath = @"X:\nuget\" + TargetName
let buildDir = SolutionDir + TargetName + @"\bin\Fake\" + BuildMode

//Constants
let constantSolution = SolutionDir + TargetName + @"\" + TargetName + ".csproj"

//Functions
let GetVersion = 
    GetAttributeValue "AssemblyVersion" AssemblyFilePath

//Targets
Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
        Console.WriteLine ("Cleaning up")
        CleanDir buildDir
)

Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
    Console.WriteLine("Building application on " + buildDir)
    if BuildMode = "Debug" then MSBuildDebug buildDir "Build" !! constantSolution
                                    |> Log "AppBuild-Output:" 
    else MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build" !! constantSolution
            |>Log "AppBuild-Output"
)

Target "CreatePackage" (fun _ ->
    Pack (fun p ->
        {p with
            Version = GetVersion.Value
            OutputPath = PaketOutPath
            BuildConfig = BuildMode
            ToolPath = PaketPath
            TemplateFile = SolutionDir + TargetName
            BuildPlatform = "x86"
            WorkingDir = buildDir
        })
)

Dependencies
"Clean"
    ==> "BuildApp"
    ==> "CreatePackage"

RunTargetOrDefault "CreatePackage"
```

I'm completely lost here, and google doesn't help, any ideas why paket is failing?
Thanks in advance, any ideas will be wellcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem... In the Target "CreatePackage", I was using on the field TemplateFile the path for that file, excluding the actual name of the file

This is the "fix"

```
Target "CreatePackage" (fun _ ->
    Pack (fun p ->
        {p with
            Version = GetVersion.Value
            OutputPath = PaketOutPath
            BuildConfig = BuildMode
            ToolPath = PaketPath
            TemplateFile = SolutionDir + TargetName + @"\paket.template"
            BuildPlatform = "x86"
            WorkingDir = buildDir
        })
)
```

Comment: Do you know if you skip the TemplateFile parameter, paket will scan all subfolders inside the WorkingDir for paket.template files and create all packages for you?